# Is there a difference here between Jacob and Israel?

Tags: jacob, israel

Contained in Micah 3:8 seems to be a pretty good description of what a prophet does:

> But yet I am filled with the strength of the spirit of the Lord, with judgment, and power: to declare unto Jacob his wickedness, and to Israel his sin. *(Douay-Rheims)*

Is there a difference here between "Jacob" and "Israel", or do they have the same meaning?

Comment: 'Jacob' is the individual ; 'Israel' is corporate. 'Jacob' is the natural ; 'Israel' is the spiritual. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Many thanks for this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Jacob" and "Israel" are frequently used as direct synonyms in the OT, especially in Hebrew parallelism.  Here is a sample:

- Gen 46:2 - And God spoke to **Israel** in visions of the night and said, “**Jacob, Jacob**.” And he said, “Here I am.”
- Gen 46:5 - Then **Jacob** departed from Beersheba, and the sons of **Israel** took their father Jacob in the wagons Pharaoh had sent to carry him, along with their children and wives.
- Num 23:23 - For there is no enchantment **against Jacob**, no divination **against Israel**; now it shall be said **of Jacob** and **of Israel**, ‘What has God wrought!’
- Ps 78:5 - For He established a testimony in **Jacob** and appointed a law in **Israel**, which He commanded our fathers to teach to their children,
- Ps 105:10 - He confirmed it to **Jacob** as a decree, to **Israel** as an everlasting covenant:
- Ps 105:23 - Then **Israel** entered Egypt; **Jacob** dwelt in the land of Ham.
- Isa 10:20 - And it shall come to pass in that day That the remnant of **Israel**, And such as have escaped of the house of **Jacob**, Will never again depend on him who defeated them, But will depend on the LORD, the Holy One of Israel, in truth.
- Isa 14:1 - When the LORD has compassion on **Jacob** and again chooses **Israel**, and settles them on their own land, then strangers will join them and attach themselves to the house of Jacob.
- Isa 41:14 - “Fear not, you worm **Jacob**, You men of **Israel**! I will help you,” says the LORD And your Redeemer, the Holy One of Israel.
- Isa 44:21 - “Remember these things, **Jacob**, And **Israel**, for you are My servant; I have formed you, you are My servant, Israel, you will not be forgotten by Me.
- Isa 48:1 - “Listen to this, O house of **Jacob**, you who are called by the name of **Israel**, who have descended from the line of Judah, who swear by the name of the LORD, who invoke the God of Israel—but not in truth or righteousness—
- Jer 46:27 - “But as for you, **Jacob** My servant, do not fear, Nor be dismayed, **Israel**! For, see, I am going to save you from far away, And your descendants from the land of their captivity; And Jacob will return and be undisturbed And secure, with no one making him afraid.
- Mic 1:5 - All this is for the **transgression of Jacob** and the **sins of the house of Israel**. What is the transgression of Jacob? Is it not Samaria? And what is the high place of Judah? Is it not Jerusalem?
- Mic 2:12 - Then I said: “Hear now, O leaders of **Jacob**, you rulers of the house of **Israel**. Should you not know justice?
- Mic 3:1 - Then I said: “Hear now, O leaders of **Jacob**, you rulers of the house of **Israel**. Should you not know justice?
- Mic 3:8 - As for me, however, I am filled with power by the Spirit of the LORD, with justice and courage, to declare to **Jacob** his transgression and to **Israel** his sin.
- Mic 3:9 - Now hear this, O leaders of the house of **Jacob** and rulers of the house of **Israel**, who despise justice and pervert all that is right,

Thus, "Jacob" and "Israel" are frequently used as direct synonyms in the OT.  This can be seen more clearly when set out in the poetic Hebrew parallelism if Mic 3:8, 9 -

> As for me, however, I am filled with power by the Spirit of the LORD,
> with justice and courage,
>
> to declare to **Jacob his transgression**
>
> . . and to **Israel his sin**.
>
> Now hear this, O **leaders of the house of Jacob**
>
> . . and **rulers of the house of Israel**,
>
> who despise justice
>
> . . and pervert all that is right,

Answer (score 0):

While Micah seems to use Jacob and the whole people of Israel as synonyms, there is an important distinction, evident in the very beginning of his book, that we should consider:

> All this is for the crime of Jacob,
> for the sins of the house of Israel. What is the crime of Jacob? Is it not Samaria? And what is the sin of the house of Judah?
> Is it not Jerusalem? (1:5)

Here, at the outset, Micah uses 'Jacob' as a synonym for the northern kingdom of Israel, whose sin is evident in it capital of Samaria. Meanwhile he calls the southern kingdom "Judah," which has likewise sinned in its capital of Jerusalem.

But the prophet does not use this formula consistently throughout his book. In vs. 3:9-10 the sins of "Jacob" are evident in Jerusalem, not in Samaria:

> Hear this, you leaders of the house of Jacob,
> you rulers of the house of Israel! You who abhor justice,
> and pervert all that is right; 10 Who build up Zion with bloodshed,
> and Jerusalem with wickedness!

Therefore, I suggest that in Micah 3:8, Jacob does not refer specifically to the northern kingdom (Israel) as distinct from Judah. Here, it appears to refer the sins of Judah/Jerusalem, which is part of the larger concept of "Israel."

**Conclusion: "Jacob" and "Israel" are usually synonymous but not always. In Micah 3:8 it appears that "Jacob" means the entire people of Israel, especially Judah, centered on Jerusalem. But elsewhere in means specifically the northern kingdom centered on Samaria.**